# Need to suspend twice under 15.10

Tags: kernel, suspend, 15.10, thinkpad

Since upgrading to 15.10, I am having suspend issue on my Thinkpad X1 Carbon (1st gen) which has been running five or six Ubuntu releases fine so far.

Upon lid close, no successful suspend happens right now: the machine stays on / immediately reverts to 'on'. When I first noticed that (about a month ago after upgrading) I simply reverted to booting into the older 3.* kernel.  Following a reboot this week it turned out that under 3.50.* I had no wifi :-/ so the 3.* kernel is no viable option.

So back to 4.2.0-19, and after some research (and looking at existing bug reports) I found out that `sudo pm-suspend; sudo pm-suspend` works.

I tried to file a bug report but `ubuntu-bug` complains about third-party repositories so no luck.  Happy to provide further details if it helps.

Comment: does `sudo pm-suspend && sudo pm-suspend` works?

Comment: Yes. The point is that I **need to run `pm-suspend` twice** as stated in the question title above.  Whether I use `;` or `&&` is irrelevant.

Comment: well, it is (to me), as it means the first doesn't fail^^ It might help in the debugging process (or not, it was a question)

Comment: Another issue is that upon resume the system is not locked.  That is a little creepy too.

Answer (score 1):

There's an option in systemd that allows you to prevent your laptop to get into sleep mode when you close the lid.

Here are **the steps** to use that option:

1. Open the file */etc/systemd/logind.conf* with admin rights
2. Add in a new line at the end of the file:

   > HandleLidSwitch=ignore

Or, **in one command** in your terminal:

```
    echo "HandleLidSwitch=ignore" | sudo tee -a /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

---

Here's what *logind.conf* manual says ([source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man5/logind.conf.5.html)):

> *HandlePowerKey=, HandleSuspendKey=, HandleHibernateKey=,
>          HandleLidSwitch=*
>
> ```
>        Controls whether logind shall handle the system power and sleep
>        keys and the lid switch to trigger actions such as system power-off
>        or suspend. Can be one of ignore, poweroff, reboot, halt, kexec,
>        suspend, hibernate, hybrid-sleep and lock. If ignore logind will
>        never handle these keys. If lock all running sessions will be
>        screen locked. Otherwise the specified action will be taken in the
>        respective event. Only input devices with the power-switch udev tag
>        will be watched for key/lid switch events.  HandlePowerKey=
>        defaults to poweroff.  HandleSuspendKey= and HandleLidSwitch=
>        default to suspend.  HandleHibernateKey= defaults to hibernate.
> ```

Comment: Is this new?  But even if so, why does a single `sudo pm-suspend` not work?  In any even, I don;t want to ignore the lid closing---it had suspended well for _years_ on this box.

Comment: I've read your question again, and I understood your problem was that the lid closing triggered sleep: `Upon lid close, so suspend happens. When I first noticed that (about a month ago after upgrading) I simply reverted to booting into the older 3.* kernel`. 

Can you edit your question and clarify please? And about your question, no, it's not new, systemd has been around quite long now.

Comment: The lid-closing-triggering-suspend seems to correspond to `sudo pm-suspend`. After which my machine **snaps back into life**.  By random luck I noticed that `sudo pm-suspend; sudo pm-suspend` works.  So there is a race condition somewhere ...

Comment: out of curiosity, would `HandleLidSwitch=suspend` work, manually added to logind.conf?

Comment: I didn;t need it before; I doubt it is needed now.  The symptons of lid-closing are equivalent to a first (and unsuccessful, see above) call to `pm-suspend`.  I don't think you and I are getting anywhere here.

Comment: I'm just trying to help...

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem on Ubuntu 16.04

As detailed here for someone else, with a slightly different setup:

[sh: echo: I/O error on pm-suspend Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496237/sh-echo-i-o-error-on-pm-suspend-ubuntu-14-04/867697#867697)

The problem was due to a constantly mounted USB stick. If I ensure the USB is unmounted prior to suspending it works perfectly.