# suspend does not work on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: suspend

I have an ASIS desktop with ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
When I try to suspend, it blanks and then comes back.
Here is some hardware info:

```
AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 830 Processor × 4, 
OS type 32bit, 
disk 239.9 GB, 
memory 5.7 GiB, 
graphics Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS780 (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
```

My installation is new on a blank hard drive.
I installed 14.04 and then updated to 16.04 LTS when the system suggested to do that.
The type of installation is "desktop" (not "server").
Any ideas ?
I was asked for this:
please edit your question and include the output of sudo dmesg and the content of /var/log/pm-suspend.log
- the output of sudo dmesg is in this link: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23265052/
- there is "No such file or directory" /var/log/pm-suspend.log

Comment: I don't recognize "ASIS desktop". Please edit and provide the hardware specifications. Thanks.

Comment: AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 830 Processor × 4, OS type 32bit, disk 239.9 GB, memory 5.7 GiB, graphics Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS780 (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)

Comment: Thanks. And the graphics card? Please edit your question and add the information, not just comment. Your question is already on hold because it lacks meaningful information.

Comment: graphics Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS780 (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)

Comment: Please EDIT your question and add that info, all of it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the info so far. To debug issues occurring during suspension or after wake-up, please [edit] your question and include the output of `sudo dmesg` and the content of `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` after a (potentially unsuccessful) suspend/wake-up cycle. To capture program output you can either 1) select, copy & paste the terminal content or 2) [save it to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Edited the question and  linked the requested dmesg output a couple of days ago but I have not received any more suggestions, which I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You better look at contents of /var/log again. Impossible you don't have log file there.  Permissions are restricted, though. On my system, I have an empty file pm-suspend.log but then pm-suspend.log.1 etc have data.

The problem you have is widespread, we've been discussing it on many threads.

[Upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 sometimes fails to sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765747/upgraded-ubuntu-16-04-sometimes-fails-to-sleep/768499)

[sh: echo: I/O error on pm-suspend Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496237/sh-echo-i-o-error-on-pm-suspend-ubuntu-14-04)

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/249560

The way to get past this in the short term is to open terminal and kill the zombie suspend job. Run "ps -aux | grep suspend".  It will show a job owned by root, pm-suspend, that is failed. It is not closing out/finishing its work, that is why suspend doesn't work. Then in same terminal run "sudo kill -9 nnnnnn", replacing the n's by the number of the pm-suspend job.  Hit enter, the device will suspend. Session will be bad when you resume, consider log out.

We should close this question as a duplicate, I suppose I mean to say.

Admittedly, there is no comprehensive solution and understanding this is difficult/terrible. But no reason for this thread.